# Why couldn't Rick just use a micro sun to power his car?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In *Rick and Morty,* obviously a lot of logic is pushed aside purely for its fun and humor value. But some stuff doesn't make any logical sense for the smartest man in the universe.

In this instance, in "The Ricks Must be Crazy," Rick creates a tiny universe to power his car battery. A literal **universe,** and he sped up time to make a people sentient to serve as his powers source. Seen here:

This poses the issue, though: if Rick could create a micro universe.... not planet, not galaxy, but actual *universe* .... why instead, of using the somewhat conditional power of a planet of tiny people, didn't he just harness the near *unlimited* power of a micro sun? If it's an entire freaking **universe in a box,** it's not like he'd ever simply "run out" of power, and he's likely smart enough to create fail-safes to regulate the energy.

Was his reasoning for this ever addressed in continuity, or is my reasoning off for questioning *his* reasoning?

Comment: Maybe that's the joke? What's that, a TV show? Are you sure this is what the hard sci fi tag is for?

Comment: I always assumed that was the joke.  Creating a tiny universe is literally nothing to Rick. By using his method he got the additional perk of enslaving an entire planet while simultaneously make them believe he is their greatest hero, all for the sake of a car-battery.

Comment: I direct you to the episode "Pickle Rick". If you ask Rick this question (why'd you build a micro-civilisation and make them do it), his answer would be **"because I can".**

Comment: The last comment to Morty ("Obviously, you really know nothing about car repair") could be considered an answer to the question :) (From Rick's perspective, anyway.)

Comment: Because of the micro-capacitance transfusion of star matter in accelerated time zones within self-contained limited spacial parameter universes. Of course.

Answer (score 32):

*Was his reasoning for this ever addressed in continuity?*

Not per se. But there have been multiple episodes showing this facet of Rick, so this is totally in character.

The thing about Rick is... it's painfully obvious to him that he operates on a level miles above anyone else. And yet, secretly he knows that the comparison means nothing if there's no one to compare it to. That is why you constantly see him deconstructing other people's lives... be it superheroes, horror movie monsters or more recently, con artists... so he could show them how their entire life is a lie and he, Rick, is the only one smart enough to see that.

Sure, powering his ship from a micro-sun would solve his energy problems. But it won't give him the feeling of superiority/amusement he derives from the fact that there is an entire universe of people just unknowingly doing his bidding. Which is why it ticks him off when one of those people comes up with the same exact plan.

Comment: I think a character profile is the best way to answer this when the OP could have even asked "*why use a micro-universe at all when he could just build literally any other power source?*" and I think you've given a good profile to justify it here.

Answer (score 2):

The battery IS harnessing the energy of their micro sun: all the power generated in the miniplanet ultimately comes from their sun. Notwithstanding the character and comedic justifications, it's reasonable that the easiest way to convert solar radiation into electric power was to let life evolve, make one quick visit and have them maintain the internal process (which is really just a heat engine with more steps). Any mechanical heat engine around a star is going to require maintenance anyway.

If you assume that creating and evolving life in the microverse is easy but that you need electricity rather than heat coming out, it's not that crazy of a solution.

Comment: Compared to creating a mini-universe, constructing a [Dyson sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) around one of the mini-universe's stars seems simpler, more efficient and more expedient than waiting for life to evolve to the point where they will take directions to continually stomp on what is essentially a 'stair climber' exercise machine. Unless of course you need to exercise your own god  complex.

Comment: @Jeeped I have a feeling that while Rick can create a universe-in-a-box, his only way to interact with it is by going in and doing things manually from inside. In other words, creating a Dyson sphere in the universe-in-a-box would probably be as tedious for him as creating a Dyson sphere in the real universe.

Comment: So Rick can make a whole other other universe.... but _couldn't_ easily create relative sized solar panel satellites around one of the micro-suns that continually absorb the solar radiation and convert it _directly_ into usable electricity? Seems kinda far-fetched. By the way, welcome to the team @james davis

Answer (score 2):

There is some debate about this, but it somewhat seems like Rick might know he is fictional.  It's why he comes up with catch phrases like "wubba lubba dub dub" and why he frequently breaks the 4th wall in an otherwise in-character scene. He is trying to stay interesting to us, because he knows he will cease to exist the moment his ratings dip.

So he creates the civilization in the micro-universe to provide a captivating narrative for an episode; the pretense about keeping his car powered up is just that, a pretense.  Powering his car is just an excuse, his real goal is to stay on TV.